# Is CUDA 8.0 now compatible with gcc 5.4?

Tags: gcc, cuda, ubuntu-16.04

So my question simply is that CUDA 8.0 (CUDA 8.0.61) Toolkit is now compatible with gcc 5.4?

I've installed CUDA 8.0.61 Toolkit on my Ubuntu 16.04 with its pre-builtin gcc 5.4, and it made no problem.

Answer (score 4):

The original CUDA 8 release did not officially support gcc/gnu 5.4.  Later, a patch was made available.  The original Ubuntu 16.04 release had gcc/gnu 5.3.1 and the `host_defines.h` header file enforced this restriction (e.g. in CUDA 8.0.44).

The official support is documented in the [linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements), and it is still at the 5.3.1 level. However, the current CUDA 8 release (so called "GA2" i.e. CUDA 8.0.61) supports gcc/gnu 5.4 in the sense that the enforced restriction in the `host_defines.h` has been relaxed to only check that the gnu major version is 4 or 5.  This means GA2 will not enforce any restriction against using gcc/gnu 5.4

You shouldn't have any trouble using gcc/gnu 5.4 with CUDA 8 GA2.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: It's not the same CUDA 8.0.**

CUDA actually has a 3-number versioning scheme. And as @RobertCrovella's answer exemplifies, there are multiple "sub-releases" under a single two-number version "number". So when CUDA 8.0 was released, it was actually 8.0.27 IIANM; then we got 8.0.44; and now we're up to 8.0.61. As new versions are released, new compiler versions are supported - same as with the transition from CUDA 5 to 6, 6 to 7 etc.

The problem is that these "sub-releases" happen under the radar, which is what got you confused - you thought you were using the same "CUDA 8.0".

Just remember to always read the full version number, appearing in `version.txt` in your CUDA installation folder (e.g. `/usr/local/cuda/version.txt`).

Comment: oh... sorry. I think you assume I don't know the 'version difference' but I understand it and your point as well. Sorry I didn't clearly mention the version in my question.

Previously, CUDA 8.0 (version < 8.0.61) made compatibility problem with gcc 5.4, but few days ago I installed with CUDA 8.0.61 and it made no problem. So I thought there may be some update, and this is the main point of my question.